# How to get/download the album art from internet for Music Player project

Tags: vb.net

Hello i'm making Music player with clean look and great design and i'm about to finish it but i want to add a cool smart feature is when there is an internet connection and there isn't album cover in the mp3 file ('The song) then the program should download and get the cover by name of the mp3 file and if there is cover in the mp3 file use it (i already done that). all i wan't knew is to knew what i done wrong in this code. The problem is Msgbox appearing and says error in downloading song cover BUT why. Is there is something wrong in my code? and thanks for you time and helping me :)

''label13 and labell5 is the song name
''download cover if internet is avaiable

```
    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then

        Label13.Text = Label5.Text
        Dim Clint As New WebClient()
        Dim photolink As String = Nothing

        Application.DoEvents()
        Dim sourceCollection As String = Clint.DownloadString(New Uri("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" + Label13.Text + "&i=digital-music&ref=nb_sb_noss"))
        Dim Weber As New WebBrowser With {.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True}
        Weber.DocumentText = sourceCollection
        Dim htmlColl As HtmlDocument = Weber.Document.OpenNew(True)
        htmlColl.Write(sourceCollection)
        If htmlColl.GetElementById("mp3StoreShovelerCell0") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim theHtmlElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = htmlColl.GetElementById("mp3StoreShovelerCell0").GetElementsByTagName("img")
            For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theHtmlElementCollection
                photolink = curElement.GetAttribute("src")
            Next
            If photolink IsNot Nothing Then
                photolink = photolink.ToString.Replace("._SL500_SS110_.jpg", "._SS500_.jpg")
                BunifuImageButton2.ImageLocation = photolink



            End If
        Else
            BunifuImageButton2.Image = My.Resources.clipart536736

            MsgBox("Error in Downloading Song Cover")

        End If

    Else
        Dim file As TagLib.File = TagLib.File.Create(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL.ToString())
        If (file.Tag.Pictures.Length > 0) Then
            Dim bin = CType(file.Tag.Pictures(0).Data.Data, Byte())
            BunifuImageButton2.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(bin)).GetThumbnailImage(600, 600, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)

            BunifuImageButton7.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(bin)).GetThumbnailImage(600, 600, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
        Else
            BunifuImageButton7.Image = My.Resources.clipart536736

        End If
    End If
    BunifuImageButton7.Image = BunifuImageButton2.Image
    ''end of code cover
```

Comment: It appears there's no `mp3StoreShovelerCell0` reference in that page. The *dotted* section in the file name (`._SL500_SS110_.jpg`) also doesn't seem to be a constant.

Comment: okay, i appreciate your help but what do you suggest me to do. I'm really have to finish this project very soon because i'm in the high school. And i'm very close. if you could please help me fix this and i will very thankful to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Study that response page a bit better. Use the developer's tools provided by the WebBrowser to find out what elements you need to track to get to the resource you're after. Test it with different queries and see what the html elements you inspect have in common and what details allow you single out the one you want. It's just a matter of research. Some trial&error, too.

Comment: Okay thanks for your advice. But For clarification this project is not my homework it's just application allows me to play my favorite music with my own music player.

Comment: The reasons why you're doing this are you own. Whatever reason that is, it doesn't change what you need to do to make it work.

Comment: It thinks you have a big heart, You are a legend, man. Thanks. I'm very close to my purpose now.